# Changing Max Upload Size php

Tags: php, file-upload, filesize, ini, max-size

I am trying to change the max upload size on my server to allow larger files to be uploaded.
I have gone into the php.ini file, and have changed the following settings:

> upload_max_filesize = 20M 
>   post_max_size = 21M

This did not seem to make any difference, as I still can't upload anything bigger than 2MB. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart your web server after doing the changes?

Comment: Try restarting your server. (^what that guy said)

Comment: Is this on your local machine?

Comment: Check this one also ... [Increase upload size in your php.ini](http://drupal.org/node/97193)